# In App purchase - Product ID always invalid

Tags: swift, in-app-purchase

I've followed these 2 tutorials but none of them worked.
[THIS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zRrs7O5yjKI&t=463s)
and [THIS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dwPFtwDJ7tc&t=549s)

1 - I'm creating the app on Itunes connect with bundle ID unique
2 - I'm enabling IAP on XCODE
3 - I'm creating IAP on itunes connect with unique identifier

When the first program runs, it gives empty array on this function (which is called on viewdidload)

```
var list = [SKProduct]()
var p = SKProduct()

func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
    print("product request")
    let myProduct = response.products
    for product in myProduct {
        print("product added")
        print(product.productIdentifier)
        print(product.localizedTitle)
        print(product.localizedDescription)
        print(product.price)

        list.append(product)
    }

}
```

This is the called step:

```
if(SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()) {
            print("IAP is enabled, loading")
            let productID: NSSet = NSSet(objects: "testIAPjuliodidier.buyapp")
            let request: SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID as! Set<String>)
            request.delegate = self
            request.start()
        } else {
            print("please enable IAPS")
        }
```

I've saw that there are several people with same issues like this. Does anybody have another tutorial which may work?

Answer (score 0):

Answer: I've tried to do that yesterday and today by the morning it didnt work as well.
After I just sent this post I've tested and worked. Maybe it has to wait some time because I didnt change the code.

Answer (score 0):

late answer 
in my case :
I had created sandbox tester account.

But I need to sign out from 
Settings -> General -> iTunes and App store -> 
Tap on Apple Id -> Tap on Sign Out.

Then on start of app, whenever the code try to retrieve products, 
The popup for apple sign in ( with email and password fields ) appeared.
Sign in with sandbox tester account.
Products list appeared.